# How to convert this .js file into a jsp file?

Tags: javascript, jsp

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

I want to convert this file into a .jsp file . I would like to know where do I store the .js files and where do I store the images . And what changes should I do to the code to make it work as a jsp ? I am using eclipse IDE .

Comment: What you're basically asking is "how do I port this Javascript application to Java"?

Comment: Yes . That is what I want to know . My basic doubt is where do I store the .js files and the images .

Answer (score 0):

in simple words `jsp` is `html` with `java code` ,

Now I don't see any  requirement of java for this page, its plain HTML & some JS.

You can simple save that page in your app and use it.

You need to store `images` and `js` in public web content

Comment: which directory is the public web-content?

Comment: if using tomcat `tomcat/webapps/yourapp/thisIsPublicWebDir`

Comment: Ok but how do you deploy your app ?

Comment: In my workspace . I create a folder . And then I have created a jsp file which has that html code .

Comment: [Please *follow* this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs92/studio33/WorkshopJSP/TutorialJSP/TutorialJSPMakeJSP.html)